# Getting Error while installing a mongodb on my local system

Tags: mongodb

> I am getting an error while installing a  MONGODB on my system like
>   this

****Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017****

so what should i do?

Comment: Firstly check whether the mongoDB Service/Server is Running or not....
.
.

Secondly use terminal to ping to localhost 27017 or 127.0.0.1 27017.
Look for the connection, if it succeeds then you surely can connect to the local MongoDB Server from any MongoDB UI Client (Robo Mongo or MongoDB Compass)

Comment: @MohitHurkat How can you "ping" a specific port? You can **always** ping localhost or 127.0.0.1 - it is your currently running computer.

Comment: One could use telnet for the same.. @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: +1 @WernfriedDomscheit 

Use `telnet` for the same